# PHP Get 52 week start/end date for a specific year

Tags: php, date

I would like to calculate the start date from `Tuesday` and the end date to land on `Mondays` in the year `2016`

I am trying to have the output

**start** `date("j/n/Y");` **end** `date("j/n/Y");`

I have looked at similar SO questions, and google searches but its for specific week #'s, or not what I am trying to accomplish.

What I am trying to get is the following.

```
    Start: 12/14/2015  
End 12/21/2015 
    Start: 12/22/2015  
End 12/28/2015

    ....

    Start: 01/05/2016  
 End 01/11/2016
    Start: 01/12/2016  
 End 01/18/2016

...
```

so on and soforth.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and hope people dont downvote the crap out of this question. it is valid, and I have looked and cannot seem to find what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strtotime` function to have the first *tuesday of january 2016* and then loop 52 times, using *next monday*, and *tomorrow*. So you don't have to do any calculation.

```
 <?php
 $ts=strtotime("tuesday january 2016");
 echo "<table>";
 for ($i=0;$i<52;$i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>Start: ".date("Y/m/d", $ts);
    $ts=strtotime("next monday", $ts);
    echo "</td><td>End: ".date("Y/m/d", $ts)."</td>\n";
    echo "</td><td>Payweek: ".date("W", $ts)."</td></tr>\n";
    $ts=strtotime("tomorrow", $ts);
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What about adding which pay week # after the echo end date? like 1,2,3,4...52 to refrence to which pay week # @Adam

Comment: i added the pay week in the last column using `date("W", $ts)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

`$start_date=date("m-d-Y", strtotime('tuesday this week'));`

`$end_date=date("m-d-Y", strtotime('monday next week'));`

It will give you `week` starting from `Tuesday` and ending from `Monday`.

Comment: This would get me started in the right direction, now the question is how to loop that for 52 weeks off a specified year.

Answer (score 1):

```
$oneWeek = 7*24*60*60;   // 1 week in seconds
$curr_ts = time();
while ($curr_ts < strtotime('2017-01-01')) {
    echo "    Start: ",
        date('m/d/Y', strtotime('tuesday this week', $curr_ts)),
        "\nEnd ",
        date('m/d/Y', strtotime('monday next week', $curr_ts)),
        "\n";
    $curr_ts = $curr_ts + $oneWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the date is less than your defined end date, loop over each week.

```
$date = Some start date ...;
$endDate = Some end date ...;

while (date_interval_format($date->diff($endDate),'%R') == '+') {
    echo $date->format('j/n/Y') . " - " . $date->add(new DateInterval('P6D'))->format('j/n/Y') . "\n";
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```